# Cypress test not finding element when ran in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cypress, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Cypress for automated testing. An app built in React with Next.js

The tests pass locally with cypress open and cypress run but fail within GitLab CI.

I access the URL `cy.visit('localhost:8000/cadastro/login/?next=/')`

type username `cy.get('#id_username').type("username_here")`,

type password `cy.get('#id_password').type("password_here")`

and click on the Signin Button `cy.get('.btn').click()`

everything is working fine, but when the page enter in the app and reload to `localhost:8000/#/`, I verified a message containing "Hello, firstName!",

`` cy.get('#dropdownMenuButton').contains(`Hello, ${firstName}`); ``

and I  get this error output from CI runner:

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `#dropdownMenuButton`, but never found it.
```

I tried to increase timeout but doesn't work

Comment: Can you check in your CI that after sign in, the element is displayed `Hello, ${firstName}`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to start the sever in Gitlab, here [Next.js Cypress GitLab CI example](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2021/03/nextjs-cypress-gitlab-ci-example/) is an example of how to do it

Essentially,

**package.json**

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "cy:citest": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3000 cy:run",
    ...
```

Comment: Actually I don't think that this is the issue here. It can't find the element but the server seems to be running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the GitLab runners cache and re-run the pipeline? That should be the first thing to do.